# Python tkinter treeview column sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a `Treeview` in `tkinter` (Python 3.6 on Linux, but the same happens on windows) which I'm using to emulate a sort of spread-sheet layout.  My problem is that, if I run the example code, below, and resize say "Column 1" then as "Column 1" gets bigger, "Column 2" gets smaller.  However, if I drag out the *final* column to the right, the scroll bar expands, and now I can resize column 1 without changing the size of column 2 (instead the whole tree view expands).  If you then resize, say, column 1 again, until all columns fit in the view, the behaviour seems to revert to the original.

> What causes this change of behaviour?  Both, how can I stop it, and how can I ensure it's the default?

Minimal working example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree["show"] = "headings"
tree["columns"] = list(range(3))
for i in range(3):
    tree.heading(i, text="Column {}".format(i))

for i in range(5):
    tree.insert('', "end", i)

tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
xs = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=tree.xview)
tree["xscrollcommand"] = xs.set
xs.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.E, tk.W))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best control you have in a `Treeview` is using the `stretch` attribute of columns. If you make all of your columns' stretch and minwidth attributes.

```
for i in range(3):
    tree.column('#' + str(i), minwidth=300, stretch=0)
    tree.heading(i, text="Column {}".format(i))
tree.column('#0', stretch=0)
```

Comment: Thanks!  So `stretch=False` works well for me: it forces the widget into the "2nd mode" I discussed in the OP.  Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview  Still leaves it slightly unclear why, by default, the widget sometimes resizes the columns.  But such is life...